# Transform ES5 code to ES6 at runtime

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

There is an option to use babel API to transform javascript code from ecma script 5 to ecma script 6? 
I mean lets say I use the following cdn

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js

and provide a source like array or object with simple code of ES5 and it transform it to some array/object/string of ES6 code?

is it possible somehow to achieve this with babel or some other tool?

I mean to use some example from here for instance..
https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5

if I put in source ES5 Code

```
[1, 2, 3].map(function(n) { return n * 2; }, this);
```

It converted to arrow function in ES6

```
[1, 2, 3].map(n => n * 2);
```

**UPDATE**

What I need is actually is to take ES5 code and change it to ES6 code, it can be via api

For example is I need API/open source that do something like this (my code is in the left side )

[Link for example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D.map(function(n)%20%7B%20return%20n%20*%202%3B%20%7D%2C%20this)%3B)

Comment: You want something like that ? http://lebab.io/try-it

Comment: @Hugeen - yes but I need the code/API which is convert it ...

Comment: Is this only for the sake of readability and reduced code size or is there any compatibility reason to do so?

Comment: I think this is for learning purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best idea is to go into the [source code](https://github.com/mohebifar/lebab) of [Lebab](https://lebabjs.com/)

Open [bin/file.js](https://github.com/mohebifar/lebab/blob/master/bin/file.js). Read all the lines to understand that script.

The interesting part is the following:

```
  var transformer = new Transformer({transformers: transformers});
  transformer.readFile(file[0]);
  transformer.applyTransformations();
  transformer.writeFile(program.outFile);
```

More specificaly `transformer.applyTransformations();`

Let's open [/src/transformer.js](https://github.com/lebab/lebab/blob/master/src/Transformer.js)

In this file I see some usefull functions :

```
  /**
   * Prepare an abstract syntax tree for given code in string
   *
   * @param string
   */
  read(string) {

    this.ast = astGenerator.read(string, this.options);

  }
```

So you can use the transformer with a string of code (not a file)

Now you can apply the transformations "ES5 to ES6"

```
  /**
   * Apply All transformations
   */
  applyTransformations() {

    for (let i = 0; i < this.transformations.length; i++) {
      let transformation = this.transformations[i];
      this.applyTransformation(transformation);

    }
```

And then, recast it into string

```
  out() {
    let result = recast.print(this.ast).code;

    if(this.options.formatter) {
      result = formatter.format(result, this.options.formatter);
    }

    return result;
  }
```

### Summary

```
var transformer = new Transformer({});
transformer.read('var mySourceCode = "in ES5"');
transformer.applyTransformations();
console.log(transformer.out());
```

JSFiddle demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Hugeen/cuosht59/1/)

If you don't want all transformations, you can choose what you want with options:

```
var transformers = {
  classes: false,
  stringTemplates: false,
  arrowFunctions: true,
  let: false,
  defaultArguments: false,
  objectMethods: false,
  objectShorthands: false,
  noStrict: false,
  importCommonjs: false,
  exportCommonjs: false,
};

var transformer = new Transformer({transformers: transformers});
```

JSFiddle demo [with options](https://jsfiddle.net/Hugeen/cuosht59/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I like your answer :-) , 1+ , This is exactly what I need to use the code directly (or some rest API) ,can you please provide example jsFiddle or something to it ? for instance my input will be like [1, 2, 3].map(function(n) { return n * 2; }, this); and the out is ES arrow function code, I need it since Im not sure how to combine all together...

Comment: Thanks :) , Assume I want to take the code which only do the transformation for arrow functions can you please show me which code I should take ? I dont want to require all the lib...I want to use the code itself ...Thank you!

Comment: Btw , the jsFiddle is sometimes run and sometimes not with this error " Uncaught ReferenceError: Lebab is not defined", any idea why?

Comment: "Assume I want to take the code which only do the transformation for arrow functions can you please show me which code I should take ?" I dont know, perhaps You can play with [options](https://github.com/mohebifar/lebab/blob/master/bin/file.js#L4). Anyway I think I have answered the main question.

Comment: Ok I made another tests, It seems to work with options: https://jsfiddle.net/Hugeen/cuosht59/2/

Comment: @ Hugeen - Last question from my side, could you please refer me to the code which the do the parse, I need somehow to mark the changes in color...for instance if it change the code to arrow function I want it to mark this changes is the code with colors like yellow marker on the line which changed, could you please assist with it?Thanks again!

Comment: What you want is really complicated and requires diving into the source code of Lebab. 

I suggest you instead, to make a string comparison of the ES5 code and ES6 code.

Some libs can do this job, such as https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff or http://cemerick.github.io/jsdifflib/demo.html

Comment: You can achieve what you want by combining Lebab and jsdifflib

Answer (score 5):

To change ES5 to ES6 you can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/xto6

You have to install it

```
npm install -g xto6
```

And then just:

```
xto6 es5.js -o es6.js
```

There is also gulp plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-xto6:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var xto6 = require('gulp-xto6');

gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('path/to/fixtures/es5/*.js')
    .pipe(xto6())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/fixtures/es6/'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to use node for it I want to use some API/rest that can provide me this data,is it possible? please see my update.

Comment: Please explain me your intentions. You have some ES5 code. And you need method where you put this code and you get es6 code? But if you you don't need it to convert your files to ES6 but dynamically work wit ES6 code then there is no sense, because ES5 code will do exactly the same things like ES6 code. You wont see difference.

Comment: Thanks I familiar with node but in this project I cannot use it :( , my question is if there is some other way to do it? lets start with the arrow function functionality since this is open source(xt06/MIT) I think some code can be used from it(i can copy the code to my machine...),lets say I want just the code of the arrow functions transformation and I put  the code (like in my post) and it transfer it to ES6, can you assist?

Comment: This part of your needs I understand. but then if this theoretical function transform your code to ES6 code then what then? I mean that if you change all file to ES6 then you will have ES6 code and you can continue developing in ES6. But if you do it in your code to transform only part then this part in this code is only just string.

Comment: I want it this for purpose of learning tool which I want to develop...btw please see my update with the last link...I need some API/Code that do exactly this

Comment: Ok, I understand now. I think that this tool which I post here have limitations, and you can't do more then what I wrote in answer.

Comment: Are you familiar with other tool? do you know where the tool is doing the conversion maybe I can you they code without the node install...Thanks!

Comment: I don't know any other tool. This is because tools like that have no use in real life. This is because if you just copy part of your ES5 code to ES6 code then it will work. ES5 is correct ES6 code. It event works in the opposite direction. Peoples want to write code in ES6, but this is not supported everywhere, and peoples use tools to transform ES6 to ES5.

Comment: It is sometimes even impossible to transform all code to ES6. For example `var` vs `let`. `var` is hoisted to the top of their enclosing scope but `let` isn't, And automatic tool could have problem to understand it because this change application logic

Comment: yes I know that it cannot answer all the scenarios but i want something like the link i've provided is it possible ? as you see it working...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for ES5 to ES6 or ES6 to ES5 ? Your jsfiddle has an ES6 source.

I'd recommend looking into the babel-standalone project on https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone

I modified your jsfiddle to transform code with the ES2015 preset it that is what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/bdrg01Lg/

it is as simple as

```
var input = 'const getMessage = () => "Hello World";';
var output = Babel.transform(input, { presets: ['es2015'] }).code;
```

Comment: I've tried you fiddle and it doesnt work,please see my update :) thanks!

Comment: yes I understand you are looking for ES5 to ES6. my solution won't work.

Comment: Are you familiar with other solution : ?

Answer (score 0):

For people who just want convert their `ES5` code to `ES6` online. Use [Lebab live demo](https://lebab.unibtc.me/editor), just paste your code and it will be converted to `ES6`.